# Is it possible to preview the .go file?

Tags: macos, preview, file, space

In my mac, if there is a `xxx.txt` file, I can use <kbd>Space</kbd> key to perview it.

but if there is other expanded-name, such as `xxx.go`, `xxx.mod`, this way is not work.

[image]

so, is there any other way to preview the custom expaned-name file as text in macOS?

Comment: I think QLStephen should work for this problem (linked above) since .go files are text, but if not we can reopen this question.

Comment: Another viewer would be Glance.  It's available from the MAS, or from https://github.com/samuelmeuli/glance . Glance requires 10.15, though, as it implements the new QL API's.